# Access sharepoint library by system account

Tags: permissions, library, scheduled-tasks, system-account

take a look to my scenario:

I have an application which runs with Local System account on one of my servers (SERVER_A).

On this server i have a scheduled task to copy some files to a sharepoint library (SERVER_B).

If i run this application with my user account everything works fine, the application can copy the files to the sharepoint library. Because my user account have collaboration rights on this library.

But i need to run this application with SERVER_A\SYSTEM account... there is any way to give write permissions on SERVER_B library to this account ?!

I have already tried to give write permissions to SERVER_A$ but does not work on sharepoint only on network share.

any help ?!

Comment: does this tasks needs to run from your app, cannot you just set up windows scheduled task to do the same. this way you could set up the run as account?

Comment: Right. I'll try.
I asked this because in the company in which work is requested to reset the passwords of users via GPO Policy, every 3 months.

Comment: It will depend on your company policy but you might request an service account that doesn't fall under this policy. But it is not uncommon for some sensitive companies to have that requirement on service accounts as well - in that case there is not much you can do apart from taking that effort into account in the admin forward schedule.